# 2 LEDs on 1 SPDT switch

Tags: led, usb, diy

I'm a beginner who saw a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kl1UPoYSAow&lc=UgjIATNDyYnvrngCoAEC) from YT channel DIY Perks about hooking up a 3w LED to a phone and decided to try it, changing it a little bit.

The basic idea is getting power from a phone using a USB OTG cable, going through a voltage stepdown board to power the LED, but I want to add another LED and switch between powering them with a SPDT switch.

I've made a quick diagram to illustrate what I've come up with. My question is, will this work? Or will it burn something? How do I check if the switch is rated for the job (I think it is, according to the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/705135/ETC/SS-12F23-4.5/1), Do I go for the contact rating?)

[image]

Also, the board is with the chip Lm2596 (Not the exact same layout as the one in the video) and is set to 3.5V (Checked with a basic multimeter) and the switch seems to be a SS-12F23-4.5 (I can't see a part number on it, but looks exactly like it). The LEDs are similar to the video, rated for 700mA and between 3.2V and 3.6V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schematic you've drawn is mostly correct and will work as you expect. Nothing will break or go up in smoke.

If we are being nitpicky: It is not good practice to drive LED's (especially higher power ones) from just a constant-voltage source. A better way is a constant-current source.
When you do use a constant-current source, then the switch will become a bit of a problem the way it is drawn. It will go open-circuit and the voltage will rise, when the circuit closes again to the other LED the charge stored might damage the LED.

But the keep things simple: just build it the way you have drawn and it will work fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the video, the host says that LEDs draw more current the hotter they get and, in this case, the phone would shut off power at around 500mA, so I reckon it'll not damage it, even with my changes, right? Another point of concern is that the switch seems to be rated to max 500mA, change it?

Comment: Yes indeed. LED's will lower their forward voltage when getting hot. The figure of 1mV/degC is somewhere in my head. Lower forward LED voltage means that for the same power supply voltage the current will increase,
Indeed for a simple hobby-project like this it does not really matter that much, but if you are building and selling a product,be aware that LED lifetime will need to be derated.

Comment: Regarding the switch: it will be fine. Maybe you will not hit the 100.000 on-off cycles when you are this close to the limit. But again I would not care for a simple hobby project. I would even trust this switch with 1A of current if it is not interrupting a heavily inductive load.